# executing global options before subcommands

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I am trying to execute some global arguments before subcommands, but subcommands are executing before .

```
program
    .version('0.0.1','-V, --version')
    .option('-h, --hello','print hello')


program
    .command('msg')
    .option('-w, --world','print world')

    .action(function(options){

        console.log("inside subcommand");
        if(options.world){
            console.log("world");
        }
    });

program.parse(process.argv);

if(program.hello){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

**Expected output:**

hello

inside subcommand

world

**Actual output:**

inside subcommand

world

hello

how can i make global options execute before control flow to subcommands. ***Global options should not be defined inside subcommands and the code should be in single file.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a workaround to solve my problem

```
    var program = require('commander');

    var globalFlag = 1;

    program
        .version('0.0.1','-V, --version')
        .option('-h, --hello','print hello')


    program
    .command('msg')
    .option('-w, --world','print world')

    .action(function(options){
        if(globalFlag){
        global();
        globalFlag=0;}

        console.log("inside subcommand");
        if(options.world){
            console.log("world");
        }
    });


    program.parse(process.argv);

    if(globalFlag){
        global();
        globalFlag=0;
    }

    function global(){
    if(program.hello){
        console.log("hello");
    }
    }
```

but if someone know a proper way to do this, please post answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom event listener.

```
program.on('option:hello', function () {
  console.log('hello);
});
```